# Node/Express: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "./app/views"

Tags: node.js, express

I'm a .Net developer going through a Node tutorial on a MacBook. I can get the server up and running, but when I try to load the page, I get this:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "./app/views"
```

I think the offending line of code is here, in my /config/express.js:

```
app.set('views', './app/views');
```

If I change it to the absolute path of the views folder, everything works.

My question is: Why would this be happening? Is "./" in a file path something that works on, say, Linux but not Mac? Yet I see it in other places and it seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It requires an absolute path. Look APIs. You can do like this if you don't want to use absolute path

```
__dirname + '/app/views'
```